# I'm getting a error: request for member 'topLeft' in 'first', which is a non class type Rectangle

Tags: c++, class

Here is my code:

```
class Coo
{
   public:
   int x, int y;
};
class Rectangle
{

   Coo *topLeft;
   Coo *bottomeRight;

}
bool asf(Rectangle *first)
{
     if(first.topLeft.x) /// Error in this line

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use pointers, so you need to use `->` instead of `.`, to dereference the pointers.

```
if(first->topLeft->x)
```